# Added stored procedure giving an error Invalid object

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have added stored procedure in my database.It still gives an error "`Invalid object`". But when I execute the stored procedure it gets executed successfully.

What can be the mistake?Any help?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check which objects got invalid. In Oracle for example you can find them this way:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_invalid_objects.htm
When you know which object are invalid, then you can judge what the reason is. Maybe your procedure was called from another, and you changed the parameterisation.